# Force Training set of iris to be classified based on Species in R using LDA

Tags: r, sample, lda, training-data

I am trying to delve into R and I am currently using LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis). I am using the classic iris dataset. I might have misunderstood something but my problem is this: when I create a training set (using all samples), I get the following, which means that some samples of versicolor are characterized as virginica and vice versa:

```
             setosa versicolor virginica

setosa          50        0        0
versicolor      0         48       2
virginica       0         1        49
```

But in my case I want to use the iris training set as having  manually curated values, in order to allow me to classify new, unknown samples of iris. So, how would I go if I wanted to force LDA to accept each sample as correctly classified by the Samples column?

Thanks in advance

PS: the simple code I used:

```
require(MASS)
train50 <- sample(1:150, 150)  
ldatrain50 <- lda(Species ~ .,
              data=iris, 
              prior = c(1,1,1)/3, 
              subset = train50)

p50 <- predict(ldatrain50) ##get info on the model
tab <- table(iris$Species[train50],p50$class) 
print(tab)
```

Comment: The code looks fine. LDA will not be able to get you perfect classification on the training set because the distributions of the classes overlap. However, the performance on the training set is all but totally irrelevant since it is trivial to make perfect predictions for examples you know the true class of.

Comment: So, to clarify, you are saying there is no way to force LDA to accept the given samples as belonging to a species based on the species column?

Comment: I mean that there is no way to force LDA to assign a particular label to a particular example. [LDA assumes that all classes are normally distributed *with the same covariance matrix*](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/6Ht-nIf_NKc/maxresdefault.jpg) and only uses the species column for calculating the centers of the distributions. If an example of class virginica is closer to the center of the versicolor distribution (in Mahalanobis distance) it will always be classified as versicolor.